# filling a multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I start out with an array of strings where each element of the array is separated by "//". e.g. `temp[0] = {"sky//hi//pi"}` , `temp[1] = {"fish//steak//carrot"}`. Now my code looks like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < temp.length ;i++)
{
window.data_arrays = Array(2);
window.data_arrays[i] = temp[i].split("//");
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to make data_arrays into a 2 dimensional array...so for the example it would be like `temp[0][0] = "sky"`, `temp[0][1] = "hi"`, `temp[1][0] = "fish"`.

However the code doesn't work. Can someone please help me out? 
Thanks. (reason why I'm assigning it to window is because I need to access this variable in another file later)

Comment: `temp[0] = {"sky//hi//pi"}` is not valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `temp` array is correct, you have to initialize the array **before** the loop:

```
window.data_arrays = [];
for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
     window.data_arrays[i] = temp[i].split("//");
}
```

Otherwise you overwrite it on every iteration and it will only contain the values of the last iteration.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/73GxZ/)

Answer (score 1):

You were close.

```
temp = []; 
temp[0] = "sky//hi//pi"; 
temp[1] = "fish//steak//carrot";

window.data_arrays = [];
for (var i = 0; i < temp.length ;i++) {
  window.data_arrays[i] = temp[i].split("//");
}
```

Comment: AHHH thanks so much everyone! javascript variable scope confuses the hell out of me -_-

Comment: @user839260: This has nothing to do with JavaScript in this case. You would find the same behaviour in any programming language.

Answer (score 1):

In your sample code line 3 (below),   "window.data_arrays" is overwritten in each iteration.

```
window.data_arrays = Array(2);
```

By moving the assignment statement to outside of loop.
The following code worked for me. (I used the FireBug plugin in firefox)

```
var temp = ["sky//hi//pi","fish//steak//carrot" ];

var data_array = {};
for (var i = 0; i < temp.length ;i++)
{
   data_array[i] = temp[i].split("//");
}

console.log(data_array.length);
console.log(data_array[0][0]);
console.log(data_array[0][1]);
console.log(data_array[0][2]);
console.log(data_array[1][0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

the array definition is malformed, the rest is close:

```
var temp = [];
temp.push("sky//hi//pi");           // temp[0]
temp.push("fish//steak//carrot");   // temp[1]

var final = [];
for( var i=0, tempLen=temp.length; i < tempLen; i++ ){
   final.push( temp[i].split("//"));
}
console.log(final);
```